# Retrieving image with firebase gives: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I am trying to cache images retrieved from firebase:

```
class AccountSettings: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
var imageRef: StorageReference{
    return Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images")
}

let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 46, height: 46)
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    profileImage.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()


    if let image = cache.object(forKey: "\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "unique_id")!).jpg" as NSString){
        profileImage.image = image
    }else{
        retrieveCurrentProfileImg()
    }

}

func retrieveCurrentProfileImg(){
    let downloadImageRef = imageRef.child("\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "unique_id")!).jpg")

    let downloadTask = downloadImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1024*1024*12) { (data, error) in
        if let data = data{
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.profileImage.image = image
            self.cache.setObject(image!, forKey: "\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "unique_id")!).jpg" as NSString)
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }

        print(error ?? "No error")

    }
    downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) in

    }
    downloadTask.resume()

}
```

}

At first appear, the view loads the image, but next time the view appears this happens:

- Image wont load from cache
- I get the following error:
  [image: Error]

I noticed that it crashes after printing "No error".

I want to know what causes my problem and how I can solve it. I think that this has something to do with completionHandlers, since the error line implies so.

I have also tried to set the cache inside my completionHandler, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried assigning downloadImageRef and/or downloadTask to strong properties inside your view controller while the task is in progress? From the crash, it looks to me like either one is getting deallocated prematurely.

Comment: How would I do that? I have read that it is strong by default.

Comment: They are, I just wanted to stress that they would need to be strong. Right now they're just store in local variables which are deallocated at the end of retrieveCurrentProfileImg. By storing them in instance properties, you extend the lifetime of the values until you set the properties to nil manually or the view controller itself is deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

please check if fetcherCompletion is wild pointer, such as adding `NSLog(@"%@",weakSelf.fetcherCompletion)`

If that's true, maybe it is Firebase's bug. The property of fetcherCompletion should add `copy` or `strong`.

Comment: There are 4 vars (weakSelf, fetcherCompletion, data, error) ，the first thing is finding out which var is wild pointer. Does this code `NSLog(@"%@",weakSelf.fetcherCompletion)` crash?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but this seemed to do the trick:

```
func retrieveCurrentProfileImg(){
    var downloadImageRef = imageRef.child("\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "unique_id")!).jpg")
    print(downloadImageRef)
    downloadImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1024*1024*12) { (dataResponse, errorResponse) in
        if let data = dataResponse{
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            self.profileImage?.image = image
        }

        print(errorResponse ?? "No error")
    }
}
```

If anyone could explain why this works, it would be appreciated:)